# How to setup Jasmine js with Mimosa / Bower

Tags: javascript, jasmine, bower, mimosa

Hey I am new to Mimosa / Bower / Jasmine js and I am trying to make jasmine JS a

Development dependency within my mimosa config. Below is my mimosa config. Notice that I am

pulling in jasmine but the catch is.... it will not copy the jasmine css files. I wanted to load ALL the files out of the core folder and avoid manually adding them to the project

```
`exports.config = {
  "modules": [
    "copy",
    "jshint",
    "csslint",
    "server",
    "require",
    "minify-js",
    "minify-css",
    "live-reload",
    "less",
    "bower"
  ],
  watch: {
    sourceDir: 'src',
    compiledDir: 'www',
    javascriptDir: 'app'
  },
  vendor: {
    javascripts: 'app/vendor',
    stylesheets: 'css/vendor'
  },
  bower: {
    copy: {
      mainOverrides: {
        "jasmine": [
          "lib/jasmine-core"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

If there is a better way of doing all this please let me know. How would one setup jasmine with mimosa / bower? What should the file structure look like?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw together a little sample repo that shows pulling in both the `.js` and the `.css` from the `jasmine-core` folder.

https://github.com/dbashford/MimosaJasmineBower